# What is the Use of defining SDK versions in Manifest and Gradle file

Tags: android, manifest

What is the use of the defining the min/max SDK version in Manifest file though we have already defined in Gradle file?

Answer (score 1):

You have not needed to define those values in the manifest in several years.

*Originally*, the manifest was where you specified `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`. Since the introduction of Android Studio and the adoption of Gradle, we now can define those attributes in Gradle. Under the covers, the  build tools generate a manifest for our app, based on our actual `AndroidManifest.xml` file and other data sources, including those Gradle settings.

Comment: Here some doc: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro#uses-sdk